# importing package written in python 2.7 into Python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to import pyofss (written in Python 2.7) into Python 3.5 but getting ImportError: No module named 'system'.  Since the package is not available in python 3, I was wondering if there is a work around to import it?

Comment: [The package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyofss) claims no support for 3.x; you could try running 2to3 on it if it's purely Python code, but if it's a C extension module, there is no automated converter, and the C internals changed enough you'd almost certainly need to rewrite it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

There is no module named `system` in Python 2.7 either; both have a module named `sys` and that is highly compatible.

As we have no idea what you are trying to import, nobody will be able to help you. Maybe the code you are looking at *never* worked, or is missing some files?